# Html5 canvas speedometer need not working with timeout()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a speedo meter needle using canvas and that is working fine with one canvas tag

my javascript for needle is

```
 function Speedometer(convas, score ,width_x, width_y ,height)
    {
    $('#Canvas_Exam').show();
       ctx = convas.getContext('2d'),
        initialpoint = -90;        
        Target =-90 +180/100*score; 
        step = 1; 

    setInterval(function () {
        if(Math.abs(Target - initialpoint) < step){
            initialpoint = Target; 
        }else{
            initialpoint += (Target > initialpoint) ?  step : (Target < initialpoint) ? -step :0;
        }
         ctx.save();
         ctx.clearRect(0, 0, convas.width, convas.height);
         ctx.translate(convas.width / 2, convas.height / 2+40);
         ctx.rotate(initialpoint * Math.PI / 180); 
         ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
         ctx.beginPath();
         ctx.moveTo(0,0); 
         ctx.lineTo(-width_x, -width_y); 
         ctx.lineTo(0, -height); 
         ctx.lineTo(width_x,- width_y);
         ctx.lineTo(0,0);
         ctx.fill();

        ctx.restore();
        },50);
    }
```

and

```
 var convas1 = document.getElementById('Canvas_Exam');
             Speedometer(convas1 ,data.d*10 ,4,12,65);
```

but when i am using second canvas tag like,

```
 var convas2 = document.getElementById('Canvas_Course');
             Speedometer(convas2 ,data.d*10 ,4,12,65);
```

needle is visible only in one 'Canvas_Course'  not in 'Canvas_Exam'  .
i think i am making mistake in position of needle.

can any one suggest what i have to do . for needle display in both  canvas tag

Comment: You have global variable problems going on. Every variable declared inside of that function are global. `var` is not optional.

Comment: Sorry , i have not use global variable , i am using variable in function which i am passing  in function as argument.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `var` in front of your variables in order to make them private.

```
function Speedometer(convas, score ,width_x, width_y ,height) {

    $('#Canvas_Exam').show();
    var ctx = convas.getContext('2d'),
        initialpoint = -90;        
        Target =-90 +180/100*score; 
        step = 1; 

// rest of your function 

}
```

Now initialize a new object for each speedometer.

```
var convas1 = document.getElementById('Canvas_Exam');
var convas1Speedo = new Speedometer(convas1 ,data.d*10 ,4,12,65);

var convas2 = document.getElementById('Canvas_Course');
var convas2Speedo = new Speedometer(convas2 ,data.d*10 ,4,12,65);
```